# Mean Preserving PDF Spreading

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a histogram representing the PDF of an unknown discrete RV. The histogram is  asymmetrical. To be clear, all I have is the histogram. Is there a known way to increase/decrease the variance of the distribution (i.e. scaling it on the x-axis) while retaining other shape characteristics as much as possible? Preserving the Mean is most important to me.

If there is a way, what would be a good numerical recipe for an efficient implementation?

I went over [this Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean-preserving_spread) and also looked on-line, [mostly around this approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) and its derivatives which aim to minimize deviating from the input histogram in terms of shape.

Thanks